# Passing an instance attribute and association method as parameters in a ruby method

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, attributes

I've written a rails helper as a part of creating data-attributes for options within a select box.

**Helper**

```
def list_attributed_options(instance_vars, attr, assoc_method)
  instance_vars.map { |instance_var| [instance_var.attr, instance_var.id, { :"data-#{assoc_method}" => instance_var.assoc_method.downcase.gsub(/\s+/, "-")}] }
end
```

**View Code**

```
<%= f.input :game_id, as: :select, collection: list_attributed_options(@games, "title", "console"), include_blank: "Select a game" %>
```

`instance_vars` represents the instance variables that will be used as the collection (`@games`), `attr` represents one of the instance variables' attributes and `assoc_method` is the model that it belongs to.

```
instance_var.title = "Halo"
instance_var.id = 21
instance_var.console = "Xbox One"
```

So for example in this particular case I want to name the options by a game's title, name the data attribute after the console belonging to the game:

```
<select>
  <option data-console="xbox-one">Halo</option>
  <option data-console="ps4">ratchet-&-clank</option>
  <option data-console="xbox-one">Tomb Raider</option>
</select>
```

Interpolating the `attr` parameter works fine but when it comes to attaching them to the instance variable is when I run into problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you want, `"title"` should be `"name"` instead, yes? In any case, `instance_var.attr` can't work since `instance_var` doesn't have `attr`; it has `name`. You want `instance_var.send(attr.to_sym)`.

Comment: Thanks  for noticing that typo. Where do I put `instance_var.send(attr.to_sym)` in the method?

Comment: Instead of `instance_var.attr` that can't possibly work.

Comment: I see. Would the same apply to `assoc_method`?

Comment: Yes, `instance_var.assoc_method` needs to be `instance_var.send(assoc_method.to_sym)`.